# php write to file one line at a time

Tags: php, io

Hello guys i'm new to php. I have a registration form and i'm trying to write each user one line at a time to the file. This is what I have but for some reason it's not working. I'm using windows. Thanks in advance.

```
$outputstring = $fname. "\t". $lname. "\t". $email. "\t". $address. "\t". $phone. "\t". $login. "\n";

@ $fp = fopen("orders.txt", 'ab');

flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

if(!$fp) 
{
    echo "<h1>Registrtion failed</h1></body></html>";
    exit;
}

fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring). "\n");
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a `b` option for mode, so `fopen("orders.txt", 'a');` would be enough. Is the file writable?

Comment: imo, First, remove the '@' from the `@ $fp = fopen("...` - You want to see every error, warning and notice. And fix them :) Next, You want to append to file. Ok, What if it doesn't exist? So, have a test for the file existing before the 'fopen append' and create the file if it doesn't exist. Do not rely on the 'it should create it anyway behaviour' as that isn't certain to work on network shares and removable devices etc,.

Comment: Also, `fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring). "\n");` makes no sense; it should be `fwrite($fp, $outputstring."\n");` (the third parameter is optional, and the `"\n"` newline should be appended to the data, not its length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode your sentence by EOL, then loop does the tricks.

```
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $paragraph) as $sentence)
    if(!fwrite($handle , $sentence)) die('error writing');
```